# Join two Mercurial repositories into one line of revisions

Tags: mercurial

Two "unrelated" Mercurial repositories are created:

```
user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest
$ cd jointest/

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest
$ hg init beginning

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest
$ hg init end

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest
$ cd beginning/

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest/beginning
$ echo "something old..." >> data.txt

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest/beginning
$ hg add data.txt

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest/beginning
$ hg commit -m "Nr 1 in beginning"

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest/beginning
$ echo "something old..." >> data.txt

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest/beginning
$ hg commit -m "Nr 2 in beginning"

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest/beginning
$ echo "something old..." >> data.txt

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest/beginning
$ hg commit -m "Nr 3 in beginning"

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest/beginning
$ cp -v data.txt ../end/
`data.txt' -> `../end/data.txt'

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest/beginning
$ cd ../end

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest/end
$ hg add data.txt # No shared changeset

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest/end
$ hg commit -m "Nr 1 in end"

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest/end
$ echo "new stuff..." >> data.txt

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest/end
$ hg commit -m "Nr 2 in end"

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest/end
$ echo "new stuff..." >> data.txt

user@SERVER ~/mercurialtest/jointest/end
$ hg commit -m "Nr 3 in end"
```

Is it possible and how do I join them together into one repository? I want to go from two separate repositories `beginning="o-o-O"`, `end="O-o-o"` (with a *total* of six commits) where they have exactly the same content in `O` to **one repository** `joined="o-o-O-o-o"` (with a total of *five* commits).

My reason is that I have converted two branches into their own repositories, but I really want them in one instead. I haven´t gotten the convert to work except this way, as separate repositories.

Comment: Do you really need to join them hip to hip? Why not head to head? ie. just merge them at the top? The histories would start divergent, but combine at the merge head. Isn't that good enough?

Comment: And note that in the example script, the first changeset in the `end` repository is not the same as the third changeset in the `beginning` repository. You copy the file over, but you don't commit it, so you commit a changed file. In other words, that first changeset is equivalent to the last changeset of the other repository *+ some stuff*.

Comment: Lasse: It´s a pretty special occation. I think I need to join them hip to hip. The repos origin is related to do how work using Visual Source Safe was (and should? I dunno) done. Anyway, work will continue in both of these branches in form of bugfixes.

Comment: Lasse: Good catch! :-) I think I fixed it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [convert extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) can do that, using `--splicemap`.